# About a surface integral $1$

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

> Prove that $$\iint\limits_S f(ax+by+cz)\ ds=2\pi \int_{-1}^{1} f(u\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2})\ du,$$ where $f(u) \in C^{(1)}$, and $S$ is $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$.

**My attempt.** Let $u=\dfrac{ax+by+cz}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}}$. Then $f(u\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2})= f(ax+by+cz)$. But I don’t know what should I do next.

Comment: For a simpler example you may try $a=1, b=c=0$, so it reduces to $\iint_S f(x) ds = 2\pi \int_{-1}^1 f(u) du$. Can you do this first? (Some sort of Fubini Theorem I suppose)

Comment: Consider orthogonal mapping: $u$ be the same as you do, $v=a_1x+b_1y+c_1z$ and $w=a_2x+b_2y+c_2z$. Then use spherical coordinate.